Question on Proposition 5.4 of Iwaniec Kowalski
I have a relatively involved question about Proposition 5.4 of Iwaniec-Kowalski. The Proposition states the following:

Proposition 5.4. Suppose $\textrm{Re}(s+\kappa_j)\geq 3\alpha>0$ for $1\leq j\leq d$. Then the derivatives of $V_s(y)$ satisfy
$$y^a V_s^{(a)}(y)\ll \left(1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_\infty}}\right)^{-A}$$
$$y^a V_s^{(a)}(y) = \delta_a + O\left(\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_\infty}}\right)^\alpha\right)$$
where $\delta_0=1$, $\delta_a=0$ if $a>0$ and the implied constants depend only on $\alpha,a,A$ and $d$. Recall that $\mathfrak{q}_\infty=\mathfrak{q}_\infty(s)$ is given by (5.6).

Now perhaps I will recall some of the notation from Iwaneic-Kowalski. First the definition of $V_s(y)$ is given as follows. For a function $G(u)$ that is holomorphic and bounded in the strip $-4<\textrm{Re}(u)<4$, even, and normalized by $G(0)=1$. Then we have that $V_s(y)$ is a smooth function defined by
$$ V_s(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(3)}y^{-u}G(u)\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}$$
where we have that $\gamma(f,s)$ corresponds to the Gamma factors of the $L$-function. Namely, we will have that
$$\gamma(f,s)=\pi^{-ds/2}\prod_{j=1}^d\Gamma\left(\frac{s+\kappa_j}{2}\right).$$
I will also remark that $\mathfrak{q}_\infty$ is given by
$$\mathfrak{q}_\infty(s)=\prod_{j=1}^d(\vert s+\kappa_j\vert+3).$$
I believe this is all that is needed in the setup of the problem, but I think there are several issues with the proof/statement. I will list them all below.
Bounds of the Gamma function
The proof of the proposition begins as follows:

For $s$ and $u$ with $\textrm{Re}(s)=\sigma>0$ and $\textrm{Re}(u)=\beta>-\sigma$ we derive by Stirling's formula (5.112) $$\frac{\Gamma(s+u)}{\Gamma(s)}\ll\frac{\vert s+u\vert^{\sigma+\beta-\frac{1}{2}}}{\vert s\vert^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}}\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(\vert s\vert-\vert s+u\vert)\right)\ll (\vert s\vert +3)^\beta\exp(\frac{\pi}{2}\vert u\vert)$$ where the only implied constant depends only on $\sigma$ and $\beta$.

Now the issue with this bound, is that I believe that the first bound is correct, but I am unable to derive the second bound. I am using the following formulation of Stirling's bound from Iwaniec Kowalski

The Stirling asymptotic formula $$\Gamma(s)=\left(\frac{2\pi}{s}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{s}{e}\right)^s\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\vert s\vert}\right)\right)$$
is valid in the angle $\vert \textrm{arg} s\vert\leq \pi-\epsilon$ with the implied constant only depending on $\epsilon$. Hence for $s=\sigma+it$, $t\neq 0$, $\sigma$ fixed $$\Gamma(\sigma+it)=\sqrt{2\pi}(it)^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\vert t\vert}\left(\frac{\vert t\vert}{e}\right)^{it}\left\{1+O\left(\frac{1}{\vert t\vert}\right)\right\}$$

Now we can get the first bound by using the second formulation of Stirling's formula. As in the definition of $V_s(y)$, we are integrating over a fixed real part of $u$. Then for a fixed $\textrm{Re}(s)$, we will use the bound. However, as we are taking an absolute value, we will ignore all exponents that are imaginary as that will just give us some rotation. We will also ignore the $O(\frac{1}{\vert t\vert})$ as we will just assume our real part is away from $0$. Now if we write $s=\sigma+it$ and $u=\beta+iv$, then using this bound, we get that
$$\frac{\Gamma(s+u)}{\Gamma(s)}\ll\frac{\vert t+v\vert^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}}{\vert t\vert^{\sigma=\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\vert t+v\vert}}{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\vert t\vert}}$$
This is more or less the first bound (except we have just taken the imaginary parts of the values which should be fine as the real parts are fixed.
Now here is the problem, we see that we can get the bound of the exponential part just by using the reverse triangle inequality (that is we use $\vert a-b\vert\geq \vert \vert a\vert-\vert b\vert\vert$ with $a=t$ and $b=t+v$ to deduce that $\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(\vert s\vert-\vert s+u\vert)\right)\ll\exp(\frac{\pi}{2}\vert u\vert)$).
However, it is not the case that $\frac{\vert s+u\vert^{\sigma+\beta-\frac{1}{2}}}{\vert s\vert^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}}\ll (\vert s\vert +3)^\beta$. It is clear that this is true if say $u=0$, but that isn't always the case as we may have that $\textrm(Im)(u)$ is very large when compared to that of $s$, and we would expect this term to dominate.
I don't know if my naive estimates are just not the correct and there might be another way to deduce this bound since even though when $v$ is large compared to $t$, we do expect this first term to dominate, but then we will have the exponential term will be "more or less" $\exp(-\frac{\pi}{2} v)$ which should be very small. I will remark that I did try Taylor expanding the $\exp$ terms and then combining them, but I didn't get anywhere. I think maybe the trick of taking logs might lead somewhere, but I also couldn't get that to work.
Thus, my question for the Gamma Factors, is this bound correct and if so how can we deduce it. Otherwise, if the bound is incorrect, is there a bound which is correct that can be used to deduce the bound.
Derivative vs. Invariant Derivative
Continuing with the proof, I shall now assume that the bonds on the Gamma functions is correct. The next step is that Iwaniec and Kowalski claim that

$$y^aV_s^{(a)}(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(3)}y^{-u}G(u)(-u)^a\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}$$

Now I do not believe this is correct. I believe that it is correct for $a=0,1$ just from taking the derivative of $y^{-u}$ under the integral, and this will give us the factor of $(-u)$. However, if we take $a=2$, so we are taking $2$-derivatives. We should be getting
$$y^2V_s''(y)=y^2\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(3)}y^{-u-2}G(u)(-u)(-u-1)\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}.$$
That is for taking $a$-derivatives we should not get a factor of $(-u)^a$, but rather I believe we should be getting a falling factorial of $-u$ that is we should be getting $(-u)_a=(-u)^{\underline{a}}=(-u)(-u-1)...(-u-a+1)$. Hence my claim is that
$$y^aV_s^{(a)}(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(3)}y^{-u}G(u)(-u)_a\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}.$$
I will remark that I don't know if this term is useful this new formula will be; however, I do have another fix. Namely, let us define the invariant differential operator $D=y\frac{d}{dy}$. Then we have that
$$D V_s(y)=y V_s'(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(3)}y^{-u}G(u)(-u)\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}.$$
Thus, when we apply $D$ again, when we take the derivative of $y$, it will have a $-u$ in the exponent each time. Hence, each time we apply $D$, we pick up a factor of $(-u)$. Hence, I believe that the correct statement of the proposition should be in terms of the invariant differential operator $D$, and hence we have that
$$D^a V_s(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(3)}y^{-u}G(u)(-u)^a\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}$$.
I guess my question for this part, is to just confirm my suspicions that the statement should be written in terms of the invariant differential operator, or if there is a way to get the proof to work as it is written, but then using the falling factorial in the integral.
Moving the Line of Integration
This is my last question on the proposition. For this section, let us assume that both the Gamma bounds and the formula for $y^aV_s^{(a)}(y)$ are correct as written in Iwaniec Kowalski. Now Iwaniec-Kowalski state the following:

Moving the line of integration to the line $\textrm{Re}(u)=\beta=-\alpha$ we derive (5.17) (this is the first bound in the statement of Proposition 5.4) while moving to the line $\textrm{Re}(u)=A$ we derive the bound $O((\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_\infty}/y)^A)$.

Now if we break this down, let's move to the line of integration to $-\alpha$, then as $G$ is holomorphic in our strip, and we are in a region where the Gamma factors won't have any zeros/poles, we don't need to worry about picking up any residues (except in the case where $a=0$ as the $\frac{du}{u}$ term will contribute a simple pole with residue $y^{-0}G(0)\frac{\gamma(f,s+0)}{\gamma(f,s)}=1$ which explains the $\delta_a$ term in the second equation. and we are now tasked with analyzing
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{(-\alpha)}y^{-u}G(u)(-u)^a\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\frac{du}{u}$$.
Now we shall apply the derived bound that
$$\frac{\gamma(f,s+u)}{\gamma(f,s)}\ll \mathfrak{q}_\infty^{\beta/2}\exp(\frac{\pi d}{2}\vert u\vert).$$
Furthermore, as we have that $G(u)$ is bounded in the strip, we get that our integral becomes
$$\ll \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{\mathfrak{q}_\infty}}\right)^{\alpha}\int_{(-\alpha)}\exp(\frac{\pi d}{2}\vert u\vert)(-u)^a\frac{du}{u}$$
which almost appears as though we get the correct bound if the integral converged, but it seems that the integral diverges which just makes things bad.
If there are any fixes to parts or all of this that people know of, please share as I'd be grateful for it.

For the gamma function part: usually we take $G(u)$ to be something like $e^{u^2}$, which decays faster than exponentially as $|\Im(u)| \to \infty$, so one really only needs to consider the case of $\Im(u)$ bounded.
For the derivative, it should indeed by $(y \frac{d}{dy} V_s)^a(y)$ on the LHS, but this doesn't change the proof.
For the contour shift, there is a typo: they first derive (5.18) (not (5.17)) and then combine (5.18) to yield (5.17) (not combine (5.17) to yield (5.18)).

Oh, and for the gamma functions: you actually get exponential decay, not exponential growth, for $|\Im(u)|$.
